# Constraint rate change problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, velocity, string, constrained-dynamics

Two small rings O and O' are put on two vertical stationary rods AB and A'B'
, respectively. One end of the inextensible threads tied at point A'. The thread passes through ring O' and it's other end is tied to ring O. Assuming that ring O' moves downwards at constant velocity $ v_1$, determine the velocity $v_2$ of the ring O, when $\angle$AOO' =$\alpha$.
[image: the problem]

**My approach**

[image: approach]

A'O'O is the length of the string which is constant.

$\rightarrow$  A'O' + h = l

${d\over dt}$(A'O')+ ${d\over dt}h$ = $0$

∵ ${d\over dt}$(A'O') = $ v_1$

$\rightarrow$ ${d\over dt}h = -  v_1$

h= $\sqrt{y^2+d^2}$

So, we have

${1\over 2}.\Bigl({1\over \sqrt{y^2+d^2}}.\Bigr).2y{d\over dt}y = - v_1$

${d\over dt}y = - v_1.\Bigl({\sqrt{y^2+d^2} \over y }\Bigr)$

${\sqrt{y^2+d^2} \over y }$ = sec($\alpha$)

So, ${d\over dt}y = {- v_1 \over cos($\alpha$)}$

$v_2$ = - ${v_1 \over cos(\alpha)}$

**But the answer is**

$v_2$ = - $v_1 {sin^2({\alpha \over 2}) \over cos(\alpha)}$

I don't know where I got it wrong and what was the mistake.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I dont think dy/dt is the velocity $V_2$ as you have taken y from O to a point below A (say it C where you have drawn the line d). Here even AC changes , so only dy/dt won't account for velocity of O . AC+CO=AO.
$$d(AC)/dt + dy/dt =V_2$$ where y=CO.
This is more of a comment rather than an answer.